# sonata media bundle modify MediaType

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I use symfony 3.4 with the sonata media bundle. Using the MediaType in a form works fine like this:

```
$this->builder->->add('document', MediaType::class,
                      ['label'    => 'Document',
                       'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.file',
                       'context'  => 'default']) ;
```

Now I'd like to modify the fields that the MediaType generates.

I just copied the Twig Template **\vendor\sonata-project\media-bundle\src\Resources\views\Form\media_widgets.html.twig** to my project (**\AppBundle\SonataMediaBundle\views\Form**) an now I am able to modify the layout. So long, everything works very fine.

The Template finally uses **{{ block('form_widget') }}** to write out the Upload Button and a Checkbox to delete uploaded files including the labels. This is done in the **\sonata-project\media-bundle\src\Forms\Type\MediaType.php** class in the buildForm method.

Now I want to modify this buildForm method. Modifying classes in vendor packages isn't a good practise, so I wanted to create a new class the extends the MediaType class an overwrites the buildForm method, like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\SonataMediaBundle ;

class MyMediaType extends \Sonata\MediaBundle\Form\Type\MediaType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ... copy code from original MediaType class and modify it after my needs ...
        ... e.g. just remove the unlink checkbox ...
    }
}
```

I receive an error message
*Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Form\SonataMediaBundle\EwMediaType": argument "$pool" of method "Sonata\MediaBundle\Form\Type\MediaType::__construct()" references class "Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\Pool" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "sonata.media.pool" service.*

I assume I have to do some configuration stuff before I can extend the MediaType in my own project. I tried with following code in my **services.yml**

```
Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\Pool: 
   tags: ['sonata.media.pool']
```

But now another error occurs:
*Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Form\SonataMediaBundle\EwMediaType": argument "$class" of method "Sonata\MediaBundle\Form\Type\MediaType::__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.*

I am quite new to symfony and not very familiar with its configuration. Can anyone please help me an list the steps I need to do, so I can extend and modify the MediaType class?

Thanks a lot.

Sascha

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following. You need to create a custom service definition.

```
AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomMediaType:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\CustomMediaType
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    arguments:
    - "@sonata.media.pool"
    - "Application\\Sonata\\MediaBundle\\Entity\\Media"
```

Then in your CustomMediaType create your formtype as per normal..

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Form\Type\MediaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\UrlType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CustomMediaType extends MediaType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'custom_media_type';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return MediaType::class;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your twig inclusions, you can add your custom HTML...

```
{% block custom_media_type_widget %}
// Your HTML here
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello Layke, thank you for your answer. I tried that and everything worked very fine so long. I am now able to modify the HTML output via the twig template.

Comment: I then tried to overwrite the buildForm method in my CustomMediaType.php class an removed the line, that creates the checkbox _($builder->add('unlink', CheckboxType::class, [...]);_ but still the buildForm method in the original MediaType.php class seems to be called. What am I missing? Do you have a clue, how I can overwrite the buildForm method? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure. However, If you want to remove something, it probabaly makes more sense just to just ->remove() the element on the builder. Is that all you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you Layke, this is a fine hint. I tried with remove, but the problem is that the MediaType creates a subform with several fields and I want to remove one of the fields in that subform. Am I able to remove a field in a subtype in my main form buildForm method?